# How to parse latitude and longitude as input values to mongo db?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern, react-leaflet

How to parse  latitude and longitude as input values to mongo db?

I have used react leaflet to get the location of a user. When I try to parse the cordinations to the DB it didnt work.

Here is the code...

Imports...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { useState } from 'react'
    import Leaflet from 'leaflet';
    import {
      MapContainer,
      Marker,
      Popup,
      
      TileLayer,
      useMapEvents,
    } from 'react-leaflet'
    import './map.css';
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
    import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
    import axios from 'axios';
```

Leaflet function...

```
function LocationMarker() {
      const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
      const map = useMapEvents({
        click() {
          map.locate()
        },
        locationfound(e) {
          setPosition(e.latlng)
          map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
        },
      })
    
      return position === null ? null : (
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>You are here</Popup>
        </Marker>
      )
    }
```

Leaflet Map...

```
    <center>
        <MapContainer center={{ lat: 6.927079, lng: 79.861244 }} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <LocationMarker />
    
    
      </MapContainer>
      </center>
```

[image: UI for the map component]

Comment: I dont see the issue here, you need to show the code where the actual issue is.

Comment: Agreed with @Disco. And in what way does it "not work"? Are you getting an error, incorrect results, something else?